# How to resolve TNS error in Oracle 11g when connect with Navicate)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, navicat

I want to connect Oracle11g with Navicate, but when I make a connection he display a error

> Ora-12514: TNS: Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.

[image]

Comment: Is your database server running locally? Or in a separate host? Make sure that listener is running and serving your host-`lsnrctl status listener_name`.

Comment: JSapkota. yes my database is locally but thanks for your reply, today i solve my problem . thanks again.  i just change the port number and oracle11g is connect with navicate. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today i solve my problem connection error oracle 11g with navicate

i just change the port number and my TESTDB is connected.

so if any body have same issue kindly check your DB port.

Comment: I am having same problem. Which port have you used? Did you change the server port?